# Wordpress Woocommerce Variable Product Attributes based on Attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day everyone,

I'm working on a website using wordpress and woocommerce, now my client wanted to achieve something more than variable product of woocommerce, it goes something like this.

There should be the Combination of attributed based on which the the other attribute will change. Example : If I select 3 Seater, then may be material  for 3 seaters will be different then 2 seater and based on the selection of material the color will be different.

Is this possible with WooCommerce product variable? Or I need to customize it manually from the backend? Is there any plugin for this?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise WooCommerce Variations to achieve the desired results. You can do this in a few steps:

1. Set attributes to something like "size", "material", etc.
2. Set the created attributes to be used as variations.
3. Create combinations of variations which bind the attributes together.

You'll have to do this for each variation there could be, and adding more attributes will increase the amount of variations you have to create, but it's feasible in the system.